# Error connecting to SQL Server database with sequelize

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database using sequelize. Here is my connection code.

```
var connection = new Sequelize(config.database,config.user,config.password, {
host: config.server,
port: 1433,
dialect: 'mssql'
});
```

I know that my config file is passing in the data correctly. I have been able to connect to  a mysql DB, but when I switched to try the same with SQL Server I had no luck.

Am I missing some connection option here? I didn't see anything about the domain in the documentation, so right no that is missing and it's my best guess at the cause.

This is the error I am getting

> message: 'Failed to connect to HOSTNAME:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED ip.of.ho.st:1433',

Here is my package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "sequelizeTest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "sequelize": "^3.19.3",
    "tedious": "^1.13.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I've made some progress. I'm now getting connection refused message. I know that my username and password are correct. The only thing I keep coming back to is whether I've specified my domain correctly or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was an undocumented option called dialect options. For my setup this was a MUST in order to connect to our mssql instance.

```
dialectOptions: {
    instanceName: INSTANCE_NAME_HERE,
    domain: DOMAIN_HERE
}
```

So your whole Sequelize instance/connection looks something like this:

```
var connection = new Sequelize(config.database,config.user,config.password, {
host: config.smallserver,
dialect: 'mssql',
pool: {
max: 5,
min: 0,
idle: 10000


},
    dialectOptions: {
        instanceName: config.instancename,
        domain: config.domain
    }
});
```

**removed dead link**

Comment: It took me forever to find this answer and I was just about ready to give up on Sequelize but this solved it. All I had to add was the dialectOptions with instanceName. This should be part of the docs.

Comment: What should be the value of INSTANCE_NAME_HERE and DOMAIN_HERE can you kindly give an example.

Comment: Trying for over 7 hours, finally found this answer, the official docs didn't mentioned this. For my case I just need to define the instanceName under dialectOptions.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install tedious?  It is a required dependency to connect to SQL Server. I don't use ORM right now because older version of Sequelize didn't support SQL Server, but this one works for sure https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Make sure you get latest version of Sequelize.

```
 npm install --save tedious
```

Comment: That was a good guess Oleg! I have installed tedious. I will update my answer to display my package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

For those having this issue in 2023, the parameters have changed a little bit for the newer versions but you can check them out on their [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/#mssql)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, you should also include the essential parts into the answer here. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34899066)