# Failed to connect to *name_server* - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When connecting to the database with sequelize-typescript, an error occurs
`Failed to connect to SERVER\SQL2016:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND SERVER\SQL2016`

Connection settings

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript'
import { environment } from '../config'
import { normalize, join } from 'path'

export default new Sequelize({
  database: environment.database.database,
  dialect: "mssql",
  username: environment.database.username,
  // port: environment.database.port,
  password: environment.database.password,
  host: environment.database.host,
  logging: !environment.production ? console.log : false,
  models: [normalize(join(__dirname, "..", "models"))],
  dialectOptions: {
    options: {
      enableArithAbort: true,
      cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
        minVersion: "TLSv1",
      },
    },
  },
})

interface DatabaseConnection {
  database: string
  username: string
  port: number
  password: string
  host: string
  hostAsodu: string
  databaseAsodu: string
}

export const environment: Environment = {
  port: process.env.PORT ? Number(process.env.PORT) : 3030,
  production: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  database: {
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE ?? String(),
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME ?? String(),
    port: process.env.DB_PORT ? Number(process.env.DB_PORT) : 0,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD ?? String(),
    host: process.env.DB_HOST ?? String(),
    hostAsodu: process.env.DB_HOST_ASODU ?? String(),
    databaseAsodu: process.env.DB_DATABASE_ASODU ?? String()
  },
}
```

I tried connectit with and without a port, the error is the same. It just connects to SERVER, but does not want to connect to the named SERVER \ SQL2016. How can I fix this error? Found nothing on the docks

Answer (score 0):

ENOTFOUND is an operating-system-level error from your OS's networking code. It means you asked it to look up a hostname  and it came up with nothing. In the lingo, your name "could not be resolved." (`www.stackoverflow.com` is a hostname, for example. `https://www.stackoverflow.com` is a URL, which happens to contain a hostname.)

[getaddrinfo()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) is OS method that asks the domain name service (DNS) to look up a hostname.

It looks to me like you tried to look up the hostname `SERVER\SQL2016`. That's not a hostname. You probably want something like `sql2016.example.com` instead. Ask the person who operates that SQL Server instance for the correct hosthame.

The SQL Server instance I use has a hostname something like `devdatabase.dev.example.com`.

**Edit**  The `SQL2016` part of your connection string is known as the *server instance* or `DataSource`. You need to specify it separately from the hostname.  See this. [Error connecting to SQL Server database with sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141598/error-connecting-to-sql-server-database-with-sequelize)   You also need to make sure your SQL Server software is configured to allow TCP connections.

Try this as you connect.

```js
export default new Sequelize({
  database: environment.database.database,
  dialect: "mssql",
  username: environment.database.username,
  // port: environment.database.port,
  password: environment.database.password,
  host: environment.database.host,  /* should be the hostname without \SQL2016 */
  logging: !environment.production ? console.log : false,
  models: [normalize(join(__dirname, "..", "models"))],
  dialectOptions: {
    instanceName: 'SQL2016',
    options: {
      enableArithAbort: true,
      cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
        minVersion: "TLSv1",
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Please tell me why, then in SQL Server Management Studio, I can connect to the server with `SERVER \ SQL2016`, and there is an error in sequelize-typescript, if I can connect to MS, hosthame is correct?

Comment: SSMS allows the use of Microsoft-specific nonstandard machine naming stuff. nodejs does not.  The good news?  SSMS also allows the use of standard DNS style naming. (Microsoft spent decades p***ing on everything until it smelt like them. They are now moving away from that business strategy because it didn't work.)

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand, so through `SERVER\SQL2016` I cannot connect in sequalize? Or how to solve this problem, the connection occurs only if specify `SERVER`, but this is not suitable, on the final object, the connection to the database occurs only in this format `SERVER\SQL2016`